# How can we find a basis of an affine subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We have the set \begin{equation*}S:=\left \{\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^3\mid x_1+x_2+x_3=-6\right \}\end{equation*}

Since the zero vector is not contained the set is not a subspace.

It holds that $x_1+x_2+x_3=-6 \Rightarrow x_1=-6-x_2-x_3$.

The vectors of $S$ are therefore of the form \begin{equation*}\begin{pmatrix}-6-x_2-x_3 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-6 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+x_2\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+x_3\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

So we have that \begin{equation*}S=\begin{pmatrix}-6 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+\left \{x_2\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+x_3\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\mid x_2, x_3\in \mathbb{R}\right \}\end{equation*}

Let $U:=\left \{x_2\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+x_3\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\mid x_2, x_3\in \mathbb{R}\right \}$.

Usng the criteria we can show that $U$ is a subspace and so $S$ is an affine subspace.

How can we find a basis?

Is a basis of an affine subspace $v+U$ equal to $v+b$, where $b$ is a basis of $U$ ?

Comment: What you have done is perfectly right. The term "basis" for an affine subspace (not very widespread) can be understood as grouping a point (any point of S) and a basis of the associated **vector** subspace.

Comment: So we could find a basis only if these sets were subspaces, right? @JeanMarie

Comment: The answer to your entire question is "yes".  The set $U$ is a basis for the vector subspace.  The pair of entities, $\left((-6,0,0)^T,U \right)$, one being a point in $S$ and the other being the basis for a vector subspace, constitutes an affine subspace.

Comment: So do you mean that $\left \{\begin{pmatrix}-6 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\right \}$ is a basis of $S$ ? @GingerBreadMan

Comment: I wouldn't write it like that, because it makes it seem like those three vectors form a basis for a vector subspace, called $S$, which is not true.  Of course, this all depends on your notation for expressing the basis of an affine subspace.  If it were implicit in _your_ notation that the first vector of the basis (of an _affine_ subspace) is always the translation vector, then what you have written would be fine.  

The span of $\{(-6,0,0)^T, (-1,1,0)^T, (-1,0,1)\}$ is not the span of $S$.  But $(-6,0,0)^T + $ the span of $\{(-1,1,0)^T, (-1,0,1)\}$ is the span of $S$.  I think you get it.

Comment: So a basis is $(-6,0,0)^T+\{(-1,1,0)^T,(-1,0,1)\}$ ? @GingerBreadMan

Comment: Yes, I think that's the clearest way to write it.  I'm honestly not sure what the convention is for expressing the basis of an affine subspace.  It really is best understood as the basis for a vector subspace (which contains the zero vector) plus a translation vector.

Comment: Ok, I see!! Thanks!! :-) @GingerBreadMan